# The spectrum of $C(K)$ where $K$ is a compact Hausdorff space

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

Let $K$ be a compact Hausdorff space, what's the spectrum of $f\in C(K)$? I don't know how to start.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: when is $1/(f(x) - \lambda)$ a continuous function?